# ES6 child class inheritance property

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, es6-class

I have a parent A and two other classes B and C that extend A. I'm trying to change the config property inside the parent class A from a child, for example B, and be shared automatically with other childs, for example C?

```
class A {
   constructor() {
       this.config = {};
   }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
   updateConfig() {
       this.config = "B";
   }
}

class C extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    getConfig() {
        console.log(this.config);
    }
}

const b = new B();
const c = new C();
b.updateConfig();
c.getConfig(); // got {} expected "B"
```

Comment: `b` and `c` might both be of type `A` (through inheritance), they're still different objects (i.e. they share nothing in terms of actual data).

Comment: That the classes inherit from each other does not mean anything about the relation between particular instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` and `c` are completely different objects.  While they both derive from `A` (which means they inherit behavior, not data), they are separate instances and thus have separate instance data.  So, they each have their own section of their object that is an `A`.  When you change the `A` part of `b`, it does not affect the `A` part of `c`.

If you want a single value that is shared by all instances, perhaps you want to use a static property of one of your classes or perhaps you want each of `b` and `c` to have a reference to the same object in their instance data so when one changes that object, the other will see the same change (because they're both referring to the same object).